# Samsung S2 installs app in device memory instead of USB storage

Tags: samsung-mobile

I am trying to check in the internet the answer for this but I find it really hard to get the answer.
My samsung s2 storage details are:
Device memory - 1.97GB
USB storage - 11.49GB
I don't have SD card

I am wondering, everytime I download an app, it's being installed in the device memory. If I download a few apps, my phone started to complain of no more space.  I really cannot understand why S2 automatically used Device memory for downloaded apps.  Also, I cannot even move the installed app to USB storage.

Please advise.

Comment: Stackoverflow is only for programming questions, not for questions about using computers or phones - try superuser.com instead.

Answer (score 8):

To free up memory on the S2, dial *#9900#. This will bring up a menu. Select the second option "Delete Dumpstat/logcat". This will free up a lot of Device Memory.

Apps are always installed on Device Memory first. With my phone, I can move installed apps to sd card by going to Settings -> Application Manager, selecting an app and then chossing move to sd card. A 4gb SD card is only a few dollars so might be worth it? If you root your phone, you can set the size of the different memories. But rooting will void your warranty most likely.